# How can sentences be handled by a motion?

Tags: cursor-motions

Is there a motion to move forwards a sentence? For example, w moves forwards a word.

Comment: If an answer solves your problem or answers your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, although sentence detection is occasionally not correct (for me): see the motions `(` and `)`.